A story where a self-declared medium speaks with the voice of a dead skeptic and calls her audience idiots for believing in spiritism
I read this very original (and funny) middle length fiction (long novelette or short novella) more than 20 years ago, in English, in a F&SF collection.
It is definitely not SF so it must be Fantasy, but with a twist.
There are three, or maybe four main characters.
Two are skeptics whose aim in life is to expose the tricks of the charlatans who present themselves as having paranormal powers.
One is such a charlatan, a woman who claims that when she goes under a "trance" some millenia-old entity speaks through her (with a voice different of her normal one). The possible fourth one....  See below...
In the recent public performances of the charlatan, a third voice has interrupted the typical New Age babble and started insulting the audience, calling them very strong names for paying big amounts of money to listen to such nonsense, since spiritism is a fraud.
The two skeptics hear of these events and attend her next performances. They are quick to recognise, in the utterances of that third voice, phrases used by an early twentieth-century well known skeptic, who had died a some time before the story.
I remember that at that time I did check that this person had really existed. But now I forgot his name.
Being skeptics, they assume that the charlatan does this on purpose. But they cannot find a logical reason for her to do it. She  is losing audience.
More and more, they start to consider the possibility that the dead skeptic is really speaking through this woman (which would mean she really has paranormal powers, which is contrary to their deepest certainties).
At the end, the charlatan, using her own voice, exposes her tricks and also all the scams she had committed earlier under different names, herself and other charlatans she knew well.
So there is a rational interpretation : after all this time the charlatan suddenly got remorseful and confessed everything. But it sounds extremely unlikely.
Alternatively, a dead skeptic actually talked through the body of a self-proclaimed medium who, while having been charlatan for many years, did develop paranormal powers for a short time to expose herself and other charlatans !

I was thinking the skeptic might be James Randi, but he was alive 20 years ago.

No, I think the two skeptics do mention Randi (whose name was familiar to me) as one who also is active in doing the seme thing as them, but as still living. The dead one I did not know his name.

"Inside Job" a novella by Connie Willis (the dead skeptic being H. L. Mencken), first published in Asimov's in January 2005.
From the wiki:

In the story, a debunker of pseudoscience encounters a fake medium who
seems to be genuinely channelling the disruptive spirit of H. L.
Mencken.

Here's where it has been published. You may have read it in Best Short Novels 2006

You are right. So it was a bit less than 20 years ago.

You were within 10% of right. Not bad at all
